# Tikzpicture: axis parameters

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, axis

I've got a question regarding tikzpictures.

Unfortantely I can't find a way to position my axis labels right at the end of the axis. Additionally it would be great if the lines would be connected if possible.

That's my simplified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                {
                    xmin=0, xmax=6,
                    ymin=0, ymax=6,
                    xlabel={$t$},
                    ylabel={$\rho$},
                    axis y line=middle,
                    axis x line=middle,
                }
                \addplot [black,domain=0:1, no marks] {6};
                \addplot [black,domain=1:2, no marks] {5};
                \addplot [black,domain=2:3, no marks] {4};
                \addplot [black,domain=3:4, no marks] {3};
                \addplot [black,domain=4:5, no marks] {2};
                \addplot [black,domain=5:6, no marks] {1};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption[some text]   {some text}
        \label{fig:someLabel}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for providing your code. Could you edit you question to make it copy-paste-compilable? That makes it much more useful as people don't have to guess how to complete it.

Answer (score 2):

You nearly had the solution: `axis y line=middle, axis x line=middle,` does the job.
However, the parameters for the `axis` environment need to be in square brackets `[]` instead of braces `{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                    xmin=0, xmax=6,
                    ymin=0, ymax=6,
                    xlabel={$t$},
                    ylabel={$\rho$},
                    axis y line=middle,
                    axis x line=middle,
                ]
                \addplot [black,domain=0:1, no marks] {6};
                \addplot [black,domain=1:2, no marks] {5};  
                \addplot [black,domain=2:3, no marks] {4};
                \addplot [black,domain=3:4, no marks] {3};
                \addplot [black,domain=4:5, no marks] {2};
                \addplot [black,domain=5:6, no marks] {1};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption[some text]   {some text}
        \label{fig:someLabel}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```